# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: TYPE 'BOOL' does not exist

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

So I'm trying to create this Table usr with the following code:

```
psCreateTable = con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE usr (pk_ID Integer NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, lastname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, firstname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, admin BOOL DEFAULT FALSE, PRIMARY KEY(pk_ID))");
psCreateTable.execute();
```

When I execute the code I get this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: TYPE 'BOOL' does not exist
```

This should most definitely work just fine, since it's a copypasted from another table. So why doesn't is work?

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with `TINYINT(1)` instead of `BOOL`?

Comment: No, and I specifically don't want to. Too much of a hassle, and I just know BOOL should work.

Comment: Are you sure you are targeting the same database versions?

Comment: @ArunManivannan yep, 100% sure

Comment: I just check my SQL Server Management and I didn't see Bool datatype. It may be tinyint(1) :) 1 = true, 0 = false

Comment: @MarvinEffing Interesting. Like Luiggi mentioned, you might want to give TINYINT(1).  They mean the same. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Comment: Open your favorite MySQL query editor and try `describe OriginTable` (being `OriginTable` the one were you saw this `BOOL` type). If you see the `BOOL` type there, it must be a MySQL jar problem, otherwise don't waste your time making problems where the solution is in front of you.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm using derby

Comment: Why did you post it as a MySQL question then? Also, derby doesn't have `BOOL` nor `BOOLEAN` datatype.

Comment: Then why did you tag it MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.*;

public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rms";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
Connection conn = null;
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"username","password");
} catch (SQLException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}

PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE usr (pk_ID Integer NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, lastname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, firstname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, admin BOOL DEFAULT FALSE, PRIMARY KEY(pk_ID))");

        pstmt.executeUpdate();

        conn.close();
      }
 }
```

This code works perfectly fine in my system in and created the table. Can you please check again.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks all fine. I think you have to use `psCreateTable.executeUpdate();` instead of `psCreateTable.execute();`. Try this and let me know.

Also, @all
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html
Bool and tinyint(1) are synonyms.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Changed from `BOOL` to `TINYINT(1)`, after which I now get the following error: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 181.`

Comment: you dont have to change bool to tinyint as both are same and valid. Can you copy paste the whole stacktrace? Have you tried `psCreateTable.executeUpdate();`?

Comment: Also, how do I add stacktrace? There seem to be too much characters, so I can't just paste it here.

Comment: writing in another answer. As I cant copy paste here.

Comment: As I said before it should work with executeUpdate().I have given the code of my program and it works completely fine. Check.

Comment: Then I will have to look somewhere else in my code, because it's still giving me a headache.

Comment: why don't you try with varchar(1), if you are willing to accept that 0 evaluates as False, and all other values as True. Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Hi i edited Try this code,,

```
try
            {
            Statement stmt;
            stmt=con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE usr (pk_ID Integer NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, lastname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, firstname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, admin BOOL DEFAULT FALSE, PRIMARY KEY(pk_ID))");
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println(""+ex);
            }
```

Thank you

Comment: hi try with executeUpdate(query),,, one more change in mysql i found that, bool change into tinyint(1),,,  so i thing both r simlear to use true 1 false 0....